# AWS infrastructure of website with another endpoint(s)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

I have a WordPress blog that serves niche content on `domain.com`

On a different endpoint, `domain.com/api/` I have a completely different Node.JS API that doesn't regard the WordPress but I want to serve it from the same domain.

It is worth mentioning that we proiritize performance and speed above all.

My thought was the following :

Set up 2 `EC2 Instances`, one for the WordPress and one for the API (Maybe make the API a `Lambda` instance ?).

Set up an `Application Load Balancer` that will know how to route requests with a rule depending on the URL.

Is it the right way to go ? Should I just use `nginx` as a reverse proxy and serve the Node.JS API on a local port ?

I also want to use `Elastic Beanstalk` to save myself the headache of configuring the Load Balancer and the Auto Scaling group.

P.S If anyone has any advice or good habits on how to build those (With S3 Bucket perhaps, over CloudFront, etc etc) it will be more than welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/729697/can-i-use-cloudfront-to-serve-a-wordpress-blog-from-the-same-domain-but-a-diffe

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot So would you say it's better to use CloudFront instead of an ALB to route my requests based on the `Path` name ?

Comment: Not "better" but probably more straightforward since you are talking about integrating disparate resources and wanting to use Beanstalk.  CloudFront also allows path-based integration of static content from S3, while ALB doesn't.

Comment: Yeah, what @Michael-sqlbot said. We use CloudFront to bring together a service from a series of microservices, spread across ECS and distributed through an ALB, as well as a number of services running on Lambda. CloudFront has a lot of flexibility for this, and using Behaviours, it's fairly easy.